# Zoom image from current position to specified position

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview

I want to add **zooming effect** to imageview.But i want this zooming effect **from current position to specified position** inorder to show other image at specified position.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

look at this [tutorial](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/06/09/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-3/)  on how to zoom and pan an image and it is quite nice.

Comment: you are not getting my question.After clicking on that image it should zoom and go to specified position. Now i am using this code--- <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5" />